# Linting not showing anymore on Spyder's sidebar?

Tags: spyder

Linting suddenly stopped working on Spyder IDE, as shown in the picture. I have tried ticking and unticking every option in the configuration menu, without success.
It started happening in the 4.2.5 version, so I upgraded to 5.0.3 and the problem is still there.
I have it installed on Windows 10 with an Anaconda install.

Note: I have the spyder-debug.log file, in case it is needed.

[image: sidebar used to show linting marks]

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by ticking, in *Preferences*, *Completion and Linting* the box:

Enable Language Server Protocol (LSP) provider

Answer (score 1):

Did you uninstall `pyflakes`/`pylint`/`flake8` from the base/current conda environment?

*If so, check for dependencies in Spyder's menu:*

`Help> Dependencies`

*and install the missing ones among the above 3 if they aren't present.*

Also, if you have multiple environments, can you check if this issue happens in them too?

You might want to create a new environment specifically for Spyder, using

`conda create -n <environment-name>`

and retry.
AFAIK linting errors "corrections" should pop up by default.